# Transferring Ownership in vector of unique_ptrs

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor, unique-ptr, ownership

I have 2 classes A and B

```
//A.h
class A{};

// B.h
typedef unique_ptr<A, AllocateA> APtr;
typedef vector<APtr> BVEC;

class B
{
public:
   BVEC vec; //error is here
   //....
};
```

When I compile the code I get `unique_ptr....attempting to reference a deleted function`

I then add a copy contructor and an assignment operator to the B class like this

```
class B
{
public:
   BVEC vec; //error is here
   //....
   B& operator=(B&b);
   B(B&b);
};
```

But I still get the same error message.

Comment: unique_ptr cannot be copied. Try shared_ptr.

Comment: @user0175554 What is `AllocateA`? Please tell me that's not what you named your deleter.

Comment: You can't have a copy constructor if you want to *transfer* ownership. A copying operation should leave the original unmodified.

Comment: @user015554: as the other said: you cannot copy `unique_ptr` but you can `move` it :)

Comment: @MichałWalenciak I'm sure that you're implying this, but just for clarity: Do **not** `move` a member variable in a copy constructor. Do that in a move constructor.

Comment: Why does the title of your question refer to shared pointers? `unique_ptr` is not the same as `shared_ptr`

Comment: Your copy constructor and assignment operator should take `const B&` parameters.

Comment: @JonathanMee Why is it ?

Comment: @user0175554 Why is `AllocateA` a deleter? Cause it's your second template argument to a `unique_ptr`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/#parameters I'm wondering if you didn't intend `AllocateA` to be the second template argument to the `vector` in your `BVEC` `typedef` as `vector` actually does take an allocator as the second template parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code runs fine on both gcc 4.9.2 and Visual Studio 2013:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//A.h
class A{
public:
    int alpha;
    A(int input) : alpha(input){}
};

// B.h
typedef unique_ptr<A> APtr;
typedef vector<APtr> BVEC;

class B
{
public:
    BVEC vec;
    B(){}
    const B& operator=(const B& b){
        vec.clear();
        for_each(b.vec.cbegin(), b.vec.cend(), [&](const unique_ptr<A>& i){vec.push_back(unique_ptr<A>(new A(*i))); });
        return b;
    }
    B(const B& b){
        vec.clear();
        for_each(b.vec.cbegin(), b.vec.cend(), [&](const unique_ptr<A>& i){vec.push_back(unique_ptr<A>(new A(*i))); });
    }
    const B& operator=(B&& b){
        vec.resize(b.vec.size());
        move(b.vec.begin(), b.vec.end(), vec.begin());
        return *this;
    }
    B(B&& b){
        vec.resize(b.vec.size());
        move(b.vec.begin(), b.vec.end(), vec.begin());
    }
};

int main() {
    B foo;
    B bar;

    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        foo.vec.push_back(unique_ptr<A>(new A(i)));
    }
    bar = foo;
    foo.vec.clear();

    for (auto& i : bar.vec){
        cout << i->alpha << endl;
    }
    foo = move(bar);

    for (auto& i : foo.vec){
        cout << i->alpha << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what you used for your deleter in `APtr`. (I've asked the question in the comments, but haven't seen a response yet.) I suspect that if you wrote your copy constructor for `B` and your copy constructor for `A` correctly then your problem is with your deleter, `AllocateA`.

You can see in the copy constructors that I wrote for `B` that I dynamically create an identical `A` in `this.vec` for each `A` in `b.vec`. I assume that's the behavior that you want. If you want to just move the dynamic allocations over I would suggest using a move constructor [as suggested by Michal Walenciak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214652/transfering-ownership-in-vector-of-share-pointers#comment44794847_28214652).

**EDIT:**
After reviewing the OP's title I felt that what may have been intended was a move constructor. So I've added one of those as well.

Comment: Thank you, without the AllocateA, my program won't work. I use shared_ptr plus your code but I also agree that your answer is correct except my own case.

Answer (score 2):

That's because unique_ptr are ... unique, the whole point that they point to an object and when the unique_ptr gets out of scope - it deletes the variable it points at. if you could easly assign the pointed variable to another unique_ptr, when will the pointed variable will be deleted? when the first gets out of scope or the second on? there is no "uniqueness" here.

that is why copying or assigning unique_ptr is not allowed , the copy ctor and the assignment operator are disabled

you're looking for shared_ptr . multiple shared_ptr can point at one variable, and it gets deleted when ALL of them get out of scope , some sort of primitive-garbage collector

Comment: @MichałWalenciak Which would be in keeping with his title: "Transfering Ownership" but **not** in keeping with a copy constructor.

Comment: Thank you Sir, @user3613500 that as always sounds very good explation